# How to wait until data from network call comes and only then return value of a function #Swift

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, completionhandler, swift-concurrency

I have a service class that makes an api call and stores data into its property. Then my interactor class have a method where I want to make service class api call and when data will be stored - return it. I tried myself to handle this with completion handler and dispatch group, but (I suppose I just missing something) this didn't work. I would be very appreciated if you help me to deal with this problem. Thanks in advance!

Service class:

```
class PunkApiService{

var beers = [Beer]()

func loadList(at page: Int){
    //MARK: - Checks is URL is valid + pagination
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=\(page)&per_page=25") else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    //MARK: - Creating URLSession DataTask
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data, response, error in
        //MARK: - Handling no erros came
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        //MARK: - Handling data came
        guard let data = data else{
            print("Failed to load data")
            return
        }
        do{
            let beers = try JSONDecoder().decode([Beer].self, from: data)
            self.beers.append(contentsOf: beers)
        }
        catch{
            print("Failed to decode data")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And Interactor class(without completion handler or dispatch group):

```
class BeersListInteractor:BeersListInteractorProtocol{
private var favoriteBeers = FavoriteBeers()
private var service  = PunkApiService()
//MARK: - Load list of Beers
func loadList(at page: Int) -> [Beer]{
    service.loadList(at: page)
    return service.beers
}
```

Added: my attempt with completion handler

```
    var beers: [Beer]                                          
func loadList(at page: Int, completion: ()->()){
    service.loadList(at: page)
    completion()
    
}

func completion(){
    beers.append(contentsOf: service.beers)
}

loadList(at: 1) {
    completion()
}
```

Comment: Can you should your attempt with the completion handler?

Comment: You "could" make use of lock of some kind, but I don't think that's a good idea in your case, instead you should be making use of a closure callback

Comment: @jnpdx added in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you were on the right path when attempting to use a completion block, just didn't do it correctly.

```swift
func loadList(at page: Int, completion: @escaping ((Error?, Bool, [Beer]?) -> Void)) {
    //MARK: - Checks is URL is valid + pagination
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=\(page)&per_page=25") else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        completion(nil, false, nil)
        return
    }
    //MARK: - Creating URLSession DataTask
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data, response, error in
        //MARK: - Handling no erros came
        if let error = error {
            completion(error, false, nil)
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        //MARK: - Handling data came
        guard let data = data, let beers = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Beer].self, from: data) else { 
            completion(nil, false, nil)
            return
        }
        completion(nil, true, beers)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This is the `loadList` function, which now has a `completion` parameter that will have three parameters, respectively the optional `Error`, the `Bool` value representing success or failure of obtaining the data, and the actual `[Beers]` array, containing the data (if any was retrieved).

Here's how you would now call the function:

```swift
service.loadList(at: page) { error, success, beers in
    if let error = error {
        // Handle the error here
        return
    }

    if success, let beers = beers {
       // Data was correctly retrieved - and safely unwrapped for good measure, do what you need with it
       // Example:
       loader.stopLoading()
       self.datasource = beers
       self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Bear in mind the fact that the completion is being executed asynchronously, without stopping the execution of the rest of your app.
Also, you should decide wether you want to handle the error directly inside the `loadList` function or inside the closure, and possibly remove the `Error` parameter if you handle it inside the function.
The same goes for the other parameters: you can decide to only have a closure that only has a `[Beer]` parameter and only call the closure if the data is correctly retrieved and converted.

Comment: Now i see what i was doing wrong, thank you for help!

Comment: @IgorŠevtšenko No problem. If you think that my answer solves your problem, remember to mark it as solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is what `async/await` pattern is for, described [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html). In your case both `loadList` functions are `async`, and the second one `await`s for the first one:

```
class PunkApiService {
    func loadList(at page: Int) async { 
        // change function to await for task result 
        let (data, error) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        let beers = try JSONDecoder().decode([Beer].self, from: data)
        ...
        return beers
    }
}

class BeersListInteractor: BeersListInteractorProtocol {
    func loadList(at page: Int) async -> [Beer]{
         let beers = await service.loadList(at: page)
         return service.beers
    }
}
```

See a good explanation [here](https://swiftsenpai.com/swift/async-await-network-requests/)

Comment: Than you a lot i will try it!